# Did our Prophet Muhammad SAW speak to Allah directly?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, allah, malaikah

Salam,

I know that messages from Allah were sent through the angels (perhaps specifically through Angel Gabreal) to our beautiful prophet Muhammad SAW. But, did SAW speak to Allah directly and Allah speak to him directly as well or was it only through the angels?

Comment: You must read about **Waqiye-e-Miraaj**..

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find anything in English about Waqiye-e-Miraaj

Comment: @Ahmedilyas do you read Quran With translation? do you understand urdu?

Comment: Even sahaba had differences about this Issue!